# how do I write the aws config file for postgres database connection and mandrill credentials?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sinatra

I am deploying a ruby / sinatra app to aws. I need to write a myapp.config file to store the credentials for mandrill email service and also to get my postgresql connection to work. I am using sequel ORM. The myapp.config is stored in the .ebextensions directory.

So far I have:

```
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql93-devel: []

options:
  MANDRILL_APIKEY:              my_key                
  MANDRILL_USERNAME:            my_username
```

This seems terribly wrong to me and, needless to say, it does not work.

Where am I going wrong? All help gratefully received.

The directory structure is:

```
/myapp
  app.rb
  config.ru
  /.ebextensions
  myapp.config
  /views
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is a poorly articulated question. The answer, however, took a while to find. And it is:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: MANDRILL_APIKEY
    value: my_mandrill_api_key
```

should be saved as my_file_name.config in the .ebextensions folder that you create in the root of your app directory where there is already a .elasticbeanstalk folder which you should not mess with.

The issue of database connecting is also simple: Use the Sequel connection string ans stick it at the top of your app file under the require list. Like so:

```
DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://db_user:password@aws_rds_url.com:5432/db_name')
```

I hope this helps somebody else, took me a while to figure it out.